# Definition of spectrum of a linear IFS

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Take $\mathcal{T}=\{T_i:\lambda\in I\}$, where $T_i:X\to X$ is a  bounded linear operators on Banach space $X$. We say $\mathcal{T}$ as linear IFS.

In my research, I need to know definition of spectrum, point spectrum, continuous spectrum of linear IFS $\mathcal{T}=\{T_i:i\in I\}$. But these notions are not clear for me. So thankful, if you introduce a reference to know definition of them.

In the case of operator $T:X\to X$, the spectrum of $T$, is the set
$$\sigma(T)= \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: T-\lambda I \text{ is not invertible } \}$$
Also, point spectrum is the set of $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ that $(T-\lambda I)$ is not one -to-one.

Also, continuous spectrum is the set of $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ that $(T-\lambda I)(X)$ is dense in $X$